# OpenID login fails if behind a SSL proxy in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, openid, single-sign-on

I'm located behind a SSL proxy and am trying to use Chrome with StackOverflow, but I'm unable to authenticate to Google's server (or any others) and get the following error:

> "Error 107
>   (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL
>   protocol error."

Can anyone explain to me why this would be happening?  I am able to access https://chase.com with no issue, so I'm not sure why the SSO function is having an issue.

Additionally, I'm able to use IE to authenticate with SO and Google with no issue (how I'm posting this )

My query string looks like this.

> https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud?openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.return_to=https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/%3Fs%3D61ca4f73-a29d-4c67-b316-6b003cf50bb3%26dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252Faccounts%252Fo8%252Fid&openid.realm=https://stackoverflow.com/users/authenticate/&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&openid.ns.alias3=http://openid.net/srv/ax/1.0&openid.alias3.if_available=alias1,alias2,alias3&openid.alias3.required=alias4&openid.alias3.mode=fetch_request&openid.alias3.type.alias1=http://schema.openid.net/namePerson&openid.alias3.count.alias1=1&openid.alias3.type.alias2=http://schema.openid.net/contact/email&openid.alias3.count.alias2=1&openid.alias3.type.alias3=http://axschema.org/namePerson&openid.alias3.count.alias3=1&openid.alias3.type.alias4=http://axschema.org/contact/email&openid.alias3.count.alias4=1